# How to define Dockerfile for application that need to connect to mongodb

Tags: dockerfile

I have written a Go HTTP server application that communicate with a database (mongodb). With the server running you perform CRUD operations and the server insert, retrieve, delete, etc to the mongo database.

My next step is to create a docker image for my application so that i can push it to docker hub.
In order to create the image, i define the Dockerfile for my application as

```
# Dockerfile References: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

# Start from the latest golang base image
FROM golang:latest

# Add Maintainer Info
LABEL maintainer="Ralf Daniel <ralf.daniel@gmail.com>"

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all dependencies. Dependencies will be cached if the go.mod and go.sum files are not changed
RUN go mod download

# Copy the source from the current directory to the Working Directory inside the container
COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN go build -o main .

# Expose port 9090 to the outside world
EXPOSE 9090

# Declare volumes to mount
VOLUME [${LOG_DIR}]

# Command to run the executable
CMD ["./main"]
```

When i build the image using

```
docker build -t app-docker .
```

The images are build successfully and i could list the images.
However, when i run the docker image

```
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 app-docker
```

and list running containers, the container runs for about 9seconds and then stop and could not see it again when i perform

```
docker container ls
```

My application is such that when i run it, it first establish a connection to the mongo database and the start listening on port 9090 for any request.
My question is, do i have to create another Dockerfile to create a mongodb image along side my application Docker file or do i have to add some parameters to my application Dockerfile. 
Any help on how i could create a docker image of my application such that it can communicate to the mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your case; You would like to connect an app that is serve using docker container to external mongoDB Server. You have multiple ways to do it, first you can easily hardcoded the connection string within your app but that way IS NOT production level use (best to check the connections), always remember you can't hardcode sensitive data within your codebase.

To properly pass data to the image, you can utilize [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) or [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) such as the mongodb credentials or the environment dependent data. More detailed example [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-pass-environment-info-during-docker-builds-1f7c5566dd0e):

Within the app you can access those arguments or environment via OS environment variables, for go lang you can refer to this [doc](https://gobyexample.com/environment-variables), from there the app should HAVE & PERFORM functions that will initiate connection to the set mongodb server. For goLang MongoDb refer to this [doc](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-go-driver-tutorial).

And lastly, make sure the app public IP where the container is hosted IS allowed to access the set mongoDB server, e.g. Firewall, security Groups, Nacls etc.

Side Note you can use [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), it will make your deployment more organize.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my plan is not to connect the application to an external mongodb server. I would like to create a docker image of my application which will communicate with the mongoDB server and deploy both mongoDB and my application in a kubernetes cluster. So I think i will need a docker image of both mongoDB server and my application so i can push them to docker hub. With images in docker hub, i can  deploy them in kubernetes but how to create the images is my problem and need some help or advice. Sorry not explaining the part about kubernetes deployment.

Comment: You can create two images App Image, DB Image (dockerfile/mongodb) and expose the appropriate ports that the App Image will need to hook in. 

Side note: Having the database tier in a container is not a proper way because DB must be serve with high availability & durability. You can use either cloud based solutions or self hosted MongoDb with persistent block storage. In case those solutions aren't fit to your use case make sure your DB tier has persistent volume when serve in k8s.

Comment: Thanks for the advice (side note), however if having the database tier in a container is not the proper way, could you explain further what you mean by "self hosted MongoDB with persistent block storage" and how I can deploy application image on kuberbetes such that it will have access to the self hosted MongoDB.  Am new in software development and would like to learn.

Comment: Always remember when you provision a resource think about DR(Disaster Recovery) and how you can provide high availability of your application. Refer to the below link, you will noticed that the DB is out from the cluster, this is to have more flexibility in terms of planning and implementing your DR (e.g. backup and restore), App that is located in the cluster is considered disposable and non-persistent which is totally against to most DB use-cases. https://cloud.ibm.com/docs-content/v1/content/67dcd76cfdb6b611e4bcf765de756a63ca5048ca/tutorials/images/solution30/modern_architecture.png

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have similar Kubernetes cluster (1 master node and 2 worker nodes) set up and I will go by the set up in the link provided in your comment. Any links on how to make this deployment in Kubernetes will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using cloud for your clusters?

Comment: No, am using 3 different PCs in my home network. All of them running ubuntu 18 and i have install and configure Kubernetes on them.  This is the status of my cluster ubuntu@k8s-master:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME               STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
k8s-master         Ready    master   100m   v1.18.2
k8s-worker-node1   Ready    <none>   10m    v1.18.2
k8s-worker-node2   Ready    <none>   4m6s   v1.18.2